# Image in JPanel not appearing immediately

Tags: java, image, swing, paintcomponent

I am using `getImage` to read files and save them and then setting these images to the backgrounds of jpanels. However, when the applet is first loaded, the images aren't visible. Only, if I resize it or scroll up and down, do the images appear. What is the problem?

```
@Override
public void init(){

    setSize(800, 600);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    setup();

    box1.setText(texts[0]);
    box2.setText(texts[1]);
    box3.setText(texts[2]);
    box4.setText(texts[3]);


    add(box1);
    add(box2);
    add(box3);
    add(box4);

    add(testPanel);
    add(localPanel);
    add(background2);
}

public void setup(){


    box1 = new JTextArea();
    box2 = new JTextArea();
    box3 = new JTextArea();
    box4 = new JTextArea();


    box1.setText(texts[0]);
    box2.setText(texts[1]);
    box3.setText(texts[2]);
    box4.setText(texts[3]);

            //*********** this loads immediately **********//
    Image back2 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "blank_blue.png");
    background2 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(back2));

    panelBack = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "CardBar.png");

    localPanel = new JPanel(){
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.drawImage(panelBack, 0, 0, null);
        }
    };

    localPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 400));

}
```

Comment: Your code posted does not show the source of your problem. I suspect that you're adding components to your GUI after it has rendered and are not telling the GUI to revalidate and repaint the containers, but at present I can only guess. You will need to post more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image may not be read it when the component is initially painted. Try:

```
//g2d.drawImage(panelBack, 0, 0, null);
g2d.drawImage(panelBack, 0, 0, this);
```